# Ansible playbook to create a new storage

Tags: ansible, proxmox, ansible-playbook

I'm trying to create a new storage in my proxmox node with an Ansible playbook, but this ends up having no free space, all the space is used.
I want to do this from the playbook and not from the proxmox UI.
I'm also new to proxmox and ansible :-)

Here are my playbook tasks

```yaml
  tasks:
    - name: Create volume group for sdb
      community.general.lvg:
        force: true # If true, allows to remove volume group with logical volumes.
        vg: "{{ vg_sdb_name }}"
        pvs: /dev/sdb
        pvresize: true # If true, resize the physical volume to the maximum available size.

    - name: Create logical volume for storage on sdb
      community.general.lvol:
        force: true
        vg: "{{ vg_sdb_name }}"
        lv: "{{ lv_sdb_name }}"
        size: 100%VG

    - name: Create LVM storage for sdb # no module for this, so using command
      command: "pvesm add lvm mylvmstorage --vgname {{ vg_sdb_name }} --content images,rootdir"
```

The storage appears in my proxmox node with 100% usage
[image]

The disk does not seem to have any partition
[image]

And the Volume Group
[image]

Am I missing something?